# Cookies not working with SqlServer session state mode

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, session-cookies, session-state

I have a .NET MVC4 application with the following in my web.config under the system.web section:

```
<sessionState 
    mode="SQLServer" 
    sqlConnectionString="Data Source=db;userid=user;password=pass;"
    cookieless="false" 
    timeout="20"/>
```

When I run the site I do not see the cookie on the page nor saved in the database. If I change to `cookieless="true"` the session id is saved in the database.

How can I get the SqlServer session state to work with cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is saved to the database when a cookie is explicitly added.

Example: `HttpContext.Session["Hello"] = "hello";`

I assumed that the cookie was generated as soon as the page loaded and when I didn't see it thought I had a problem. But this is incorrect and now I correctly see the cookie when I add to the session state.